# Flutter get_it vs static class

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the advantage of using flutter get_it instead of a static class, which provides static methods that fulfill a service? I couldn't find a lot on the internet, except that get_it will provide a singleton so it can extend other classes.

Comment: Short answer: testing & extensibility. There are no inherent performance issues/advantages between the two.